# Firestore query collections based on permission inside a sub-collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called "project" with some documents. Each document in this collection has a subcollection called "collaborators".

```
project
  - document 1 {author: user x}
      collaborators
        - user 1
        - user 2
  - document 2 {author: user y}
      collaborators
        - user 3
  - ...
```

The documents can be viewed by the owner of the document and the collaborators. I have created Firebase rules accordingly.

```
function canRead() {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/project/$(ID)/collaborators/$(request.auth.uid)).data.read == true;
}
allow read: if isLoggedIn() && (request.auth.uid == resource.data.author || canRead())
```

I can query documents owned by a user using:

```
query(
  collection(db, "project"),
  where("author", "==", "<user id>")
)
```

However, I cannot query all documents where a user is a collaborator. Removing the where clause does not list all documents because Firestore rules aren't filters.

My other thought was to update documents with the field something like `sharedWith: ["user 1", "user 2", ...]` whenever there is an add or delete to the collaborators subcollection. However the problem with that is that all collaborators can view the sharedWith list not just the author. Additionally, if the list of collaborators gets big, this array becomes big too + probably issues with race conditions while updating this array.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Your security can work for a read of a single document (i.e. a `get` request), but not for a query across multiple documents.

The reason for that is that a Firestore query can only filter on data that is inside the document that it returns, so it can't filter on the data from the `collaborators` subcollection.

The common workaround is indeed to include the necessary data about the collaborators in the parent document itself, and check on that both in the query and in the security rules.